# Delete List Entries Containing a Button?

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have an accounting app with a screen that displays two views. One view displays **Currently In Use Categories** and another that displays **Available Categories**. The user may select which categories to use and remove other not needed. Tapping on a category in either box immediately moves the category to the other category box. These programmed categories may not be deleted.

In addition, the user may create their own optional categories. **The trouble I'm having is deleting the optional categories.** (The Add New Category works fine.) I know how to normally implement view delete using List and ForEach but this seems somewhat different. If I add onDelete at the bottom of the ForEach loop and change the **VStack** to a **List** I don't see any entries in the list. Changing the List to a VStack displays the categories in the list but doesn't let me delete any categories. Another possible problem is dragging a category to the left for deletion may also trigger the switch view button.

I am filtering the data because I was getting gaps in the lists for categories currently in the other view.

The code below is the logic for displaying the Currently In Use box.

```
struct GetCurrentCats: View {

    var g: GeometryProxy

    @State private var showStatus: Bool = false

    @Binding var presentAlert: Bool
    @Binding var presentDetail: String

    @EnvironmentObject var categories: Categories

    var body: some View {
      
        //VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
        List {
            ForEach(categories.filteredInUse, id: \.id) { item in

                Button(action: {
                    if item.catTotal == 0.0 { // must have a zero balance to remove

                        withAnimation {
                            showStatus = false

                            // Change the state of category
                            categories.setCatShow(forId: item.id)
                        }
                    } else {
                        presentAlert = true
                        presentDetail = item.catName
                    }
                }){
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: item.catPix)
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemOrange))
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                            .frame(width: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? g.size.width * 0.40 : g.size.width * 0.20)

                        Text(item.catName)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                            .background(item.catTotal != 0.0 ? Color(.systemRed) : Color(.systemBlue))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteCurCat)
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
    func deleteCurCat(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        categories.catItem.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
```

**Here is class Categories:**

```
// working categories
struct CatModel:  Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var catName: String     // category name
    var catTotal: Double    // category total
    var catBudget: Double   // category budget
    var catPix: String      // sf symbol
    var catShow: Bool

    /// Provides a new instance, toggling `catShow`.
        var toggleCatShow: CatModel {

            // Note: by creating a new instance, the new id will be different
            CatModel(catName: catName, catTotal: catTotal, catBudget: catBudget, catPix: catPix, catShow: !catShow)
    }
}


class Categories: ObservableObject {

    @Published var filteredInUse: [CatModel] = []
    @Published var filteredNotInUse: [CatModel] = []

    @Published var catItem: [CatModel] {
        didSet {
            self.save()
         
        }
    }

    init() {

        // read in category data
        if let catItem = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: StorageKeys.workCat.rawValue) {
            if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([CatModel].self, from: catItem) {
                self.catItem = decoded
                self.updateStatus()
                return
            }
        }

        catItem = []

        // catShow: 1 = category available for use; 2 = category currently being used
        let item0 = CatModel(catName: "Lodging", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "bed.double.fill", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item0)

        let item1 = CatModel(catName: "Food", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "cart", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item1)

        let item2 = CatModel(catName: "Airplane", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "airplane", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item2)

        let item3 = CatModel(catName: "Train", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "tram", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item3)

        let item4 = CatModel(catName: "Bus", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "bus.fill", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item4)

        let item5 = CatModel(catName: "Ferry", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "ferry", catShow: false)  // "helm"
        self.catItem.append(item5)

        let item6 = CatModel(catName: "Local Transit", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "textbox", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item6)

        let item7 = CatModel(catName: "Sightseeing  ", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "photo", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item7)

        let item8 = CatModel(catName: "Entertainment", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "music.mic", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item8)

        let item9 = CatModel(catName: "Souvenirs", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "gift", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item9)

        let item10 = CatModel(catName: "Laundry", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "scribble", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item10)

        let item11 = CatModel(catName: "Rental Car", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "car", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item11)

        let item12 = CatModel(catName: "Fuel", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "fuelpump", catShow: false)   // gauge
        self.catItem.append(item12)

        let item13 = CatModel(catName: "Parking", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "parkingsign.circle", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item13)

        self.updateStatus()
    }

    func updateStatus() {
        filteredInUse = catItem.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return user.catShow == true
        })

        filteredNotInUse = catItem.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return user.catShow == false
        })
    }



    // Replaces an instance of `CatModel` by changing its `catShow` value.
       func setCatShow(forId id: UUID) {
           let index = catItem.firstIndex { $0.id == id }
           if let index = index {
               catItem.replaceSubrange(index...index, with: [catItem[index].toggleCatShow])
           }

           // Refresh the filtered arrays
           updateStatus()
       }

        add new optional category (8 max)
    func addNewCatetory(catName: String) -> () {

        let item = CatModel(catName: catName, catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "person.2", catShow: true)
        catItem.append(item)
    }
}
```

Here is the upper piece of my Update Categories logic. If I run the example code with GetCurrentCats(), it displays the programmed categories. If I include this upper portion of the logic that sets up the two boxes and text above and below each box then GetCurrentCats doesn't display any programmed categories but GetAvailableCats() does display its categories. It appears to be something with the onDelete in GetCurrentCats that it doesn't like.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var categories: Categories

    @State private var presentAlert = false
    @State private var presentDetail: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { g in

            VStack (alignment: .center) {

                Text("Current Categories")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    .padding(.top, 6)
                    .padding(.bottom, -3)

                ScrollView {
                    GetCurrentCats(g: g, presentAlert: $presentAlert, presentDetail: $presentDetail)

                } .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.80, height: g.size.height * 0.35)
                    .border(Color(.systemBlue), width: 4)

                Text("Tap category to remove from system.")
                    .font(.footnote)
                Text("Red categories have a nonzero balance.")
                    .font(.footnote)
                Text("Categories must have a zero balance to remove.")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .padding(.bottom, g.size.height * 0.04)

                Text("Available Categories")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(.top, g.size.height * 0.05)
                    .padding(.bottom, -3)

                ScrollView {
                    GetAvailableCats(g: g)

                } .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.80, height: g.size.height * 0.35).border(Color(.systemBlue), width: 4)

                Text("Tap category to add to system.")
                    .font(.footnote)

            }.alert(
                "Unable to remove category.", isPresented: $presentAlert,
                presenting: presentDetail
            ) { detail in

                Button("OK") {}
            } message: { detail in
                Text("\(presentDetail) category has a nonzero balance.")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Setup Categories", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        /*    .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink (destination: AddCatView()) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
            })  */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that in your code you are using `ForEach(categories.filteredInUse,...)`, that is, looping over `categories.filteredInUse`,
 but you are deleting in `deleteCurCat` from `categories.catItem`, and the two are probably not related (judging by the code of your previous question).

Comment: Yes, filteredInUse is a subset of the categories contained in catItem[CatModel]. If I delete a category from filteredInUse I would think that it would have no impact on catItem[CatModel]. The current delete code is expecting an index whereas the ForEach is not providing an index. So is there a possible workaround?

Comment: show the code you use now for `class Categories: ObservableObject {...}`.
Your comment (and previous code) suggest, there is no link between the two arrays of `CatModel` (`catItem` and `filteredInUse`).
 The `IndexSet` in `deleteCurCat` is from the `filteredInUse` array, you should not use it for `catItem`.
 You could however, use the `id` of the category in `deleteCurCat` to delete it in
 `catItem`. In `deleteCurCat` add a simple `print("indexSet: \(indexSet)")` to check the index.

Comment: Now included the class Categories. Testing your suggestions...

Comment: I don't see your `class Categories` included in your post.

Comment: Hi workingdog: the class Categories is present in the above edited listing. Sorry, I forgot to hit the save button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not be using duplicate, triplicate arrays to store `CatModels` of different
`catShow` values. Use only one array `catItem` and filter the array according to your needs.
Such as:
`filteredInUse` equivalent, use `categories.catItem.filter{ $0.catShow.wrappedValue }` and
`filteredNotInUse` equivalent, use `categories.catItem.filter{ !$0.catShow.wrappedValue }` in the `ForEach` loop.

I've updated your code using this approach.

```
// working categories
struct CatModel:  Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var catName: String     // category name
    var catTotal: Double    // category total
    var catBudget: Double   // category budget
    var catPix: String      // sf symbol
    var catShow: Bool
}

class Categories: ObservableObject {
    // the array of CatModel
    @Published var catItem: [CatModel] {
        didSet {
            //   self.save()
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        
        // you should not use this to store the array of CatModels.
        // UserDefaults is meant to be used only for small amount of data.
        
        // read in category data
//        if let catItem = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: StorageKeys.workCat.rawValue) {
//            if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([CatModel].self, from: catItem) {
//                self.catItem = decoded
//                return
//            }
//        }
        
        catItem = []
        
        let item0 = CatModel(catName: "Lodging", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "bed.double.fill", catShow: true)
        self.catItem.append(item0)
        
        let item1 = CatModel(catName: "Food", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "cart", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item1)
        
        let item2 = CatModel(catName: "Airplane", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "airplane", catShow: true)
        self.catItem.append(item2)
        
        let item3 = CatModel(catName: "Train", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "tram", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item3)
        
        let item4 = CatModel(catName: "Bus", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "bus.fill", catShow: true)
        self.catItem.append(item4)
        
        let item5 = CatModel(catName: "Ferry", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "ferry", catShow: false)  // "helm"
        self.catItem.append(item5)
        
        let item6 = CatModel(catName: "Local Transit", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "textbox", catShow: true)
        self.catItem.append(item6)
        
        let item7 = CatModel(catName: "Sightseeing  ", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "photo", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item7)
        
        let item8 = CatModel(catName: "Entertainment", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "music.mic", catShow: true)
        self.catItem.append(item8)
        
        let item9 = CatModel(catName: "Souvenirs", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "gift", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item9)
        
        let item10 = CatModel(catName: "Laundry", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "scribble", catShow: true)
        self.catItem.append(item10)
        
        let item11 = CatModel(catName: "Rental Car", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "car", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item11)
        
        let item12 = CatModel(catName: "Fuel", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "fuelpump", catShow: true)   // gauge
        self.catItem.append(item12)
        
        let item13 = CatModel(catName: "Parking", catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "parkingsign.circle", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item13)
        
    }
    
    // add new optional category (8 max)
    func addNewCatetory(catName: String) {
        catItem.append(CatModel(catName: catName, catTotal: 0.0, catBudget: 0, catPix: "person.2", catShow: true))
    }
}

// for testing
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var categories = Categories()
    @State var presentAlert = false
    @State var presentDetail: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geom in
            GetCurrentCats(g: geom, presentAlert: $presentAlert, presentDetail: $presentDetail)
                .environmentObject(categories)
        }
    }
}

struct GetCurrentCats: View {
    
    var g: GeometryProxy
    
    @Binding var presentAlert: Bool
    @Binding var presentDetail: String
    
    @EnvironmentObject var categories: Categories
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
            List {
                // catShow=true , filteredInUse equivalent list
                ForEach($categories.catItem.filter{ $0.catShow.wrappedValue }, id: \.id) { $item in
                    Button(action: {
                        if item.catTotal == 0.0 { // must have a zero balance to remove
                            withAnimation {
                                // Change the state of category
                                item.catShow = true
                            }
                        } else {
                            presentAlert = true
                            presentDetail = item.catName
                        }
                    }){
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: item.catPix)
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.systemOrange))
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                .frame(width: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? g.size.width * 0.40 : g.size.width * 0.20)
                            
                            Text(item.catName)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                                .background(item.catTotal != 0.0 ? Color(.systemRed) : Color(.systemBlue))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                        }
                    }
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteCurCat)
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteCurCat(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        if let index = indexSet.first {
            // you have to filter exactly like in the ForEach
            let cats = categories.catItem.filter({ $0.catShow })
            if index < cats.count {
                if let ndx = categories.catItem.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == cats[index].id }) {
                    //  categories.catItem.remove(at: ndx)  // if you want to totally remove the catItem
                    // to switch/transfer category, just toggle the catShow
                    categories.catItem[ndx].catShow.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT-1: to show the list of categories:

Remove the `ScrollView` (recommended solution), or set the frame of `GetCurrentCats`, such as:

```
ScrollView {
    GetCurrentCats(g: g, presentAlert: $presentAlert, presentDetail: $presentDetail)
        .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.80, height: g.size.height * 0.35)
}
.frame(width: g.size.width * 0.80, height: g.size.height * 0.35)
.border(Color(.systemBlue), width: 4)
```

Comment: The code above (GetCurrentCats) displays the currently in use categories. In the code for GetAvaiableCats() I used GetCurrentCats() with a few tweaks including changing $0.catShow.wrappedValue by adding an ! in front of $0 and it works fine. I still can’t get GetCurrentCats() to work. Really wierd. It appears to skip all the contents of ForEach(). if I change List { to Group { GetCurrentCats() displays the entries.

Comment: I liked what you did to clean up the class, but the user selected categories aren’t being saved between startups. So what you are saying is I shouldn’t be using userDefaults for this kind of data. At max I expect 14 selectable categories + 8 user optional categories.
Currently I am using coreData for expense transactions. Is it possible to add second coreData storage system for the categories?

Comment: are you saying that my example code as shown, does not work for you? Using coreData to store your categories data is a good choice. It can be in addition to your expense transactions without any problems. Since the data you have is small, you could keep using `userDefaults` until you are ready for coreData. Note, I changed your `catShow` values of `item0, etc...` in `Categories` in my example code
 so that the data will show in the `ForEach` loop.

Comment: The example codes does run. In my actual code it appears to be some kind of interaction with onDelete preventing the display of categories.

Comment: my version of `GetCurrentCats` is essentially the same as your `GetCurrentCats` code with some mods.
 If yours does not work, then use mine, it works very well.
 I suspect the code you are showing us, is not representative of the actual code you use.
 Is that correct?, your question does not relate to the code you are showing us.

Comment: Ok I brought in the upper portion of the Update Categories logic above. this sets up the two boxes and text above and below each box before displaying the categories in each box. I am using your version of GetCurrentCats()

Comment: just remove the `ScrollViews`, your categories are already in a `List`,
 which is similar to a ScrollView.

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution for your display problem. Works for me.